# Как удалить при помощи регулярного выражения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
b609/9.2/d.0.30ct/3300-660d
b615/141.5/18k/d6.0ct/50000/5700d-gold
b618/9.4/18k/d.0.90ct/3900-780d-ring
b619/5.0/18k/d.0.45ct/2100/420d-rings
```

Подскажите, как при помощи рег. выражения Sublime удалить все, кроме первого кода `b609` в строках такого вида.

Comment: Пример самого текста можно? Описание в вопросе размывчатое.

Comment: И что вам нужно оставить здесь? В вопросе другая строка.

Comment: К примеру в строке "b609/9.2/d.0.30ct/3300-660d" нужно чтобы осталось только b609

Comment: В `awk` в одну строчку без регулярок можно `awk -F/ '{print $1}' file_name` но думаю ты на виндею

Comment: Попробуйте так: `(?:^[\S]{4})`

Comment: Что получиться-то должно? Мне лень на все 4 варианта ответы писать.

Answer (score 1):

Find: `(?<=.{4}\/).*`

Replace: ""

Answer (score 1):

Вызвать сочетанием клавиш `cntr + h` окно для замены
Выставить активной кнопку `.*`
в строку Find ввести `([^/]+).*`
в строку Replace `$1`
Нажать кнопку `Replace ALL`

Answer (score -1):

Вы просто хотите из файла с записями получить первую колонку? При наличии Linux или утилит GNU под windows или WSL, это делается [при помощи awk](https://www.shellhacks.com/ru/awk-print-column-change-field-separator-linux-bash/) примерно так.

```
echo "5879/8.18gr/18K/GOLD-ring-44, QR" | awk -F "/" '{print $1}'
```

Или для случая файла с записями `awk -F "/" '{print $1}' filename.txt > filename.out`

Comment: Все верно, можете тольтко скрин в тексте представить и у вас лишний `cat` awk умеет читать файлы.